# SQL query with having clause returns unexpected results

Tags: sql, having

I am working with Chinook database and would like to write a query that returns genres most sold in USA. My idea uses having clause and returns table which is wrong.

I've already written something that works that doesn't use having clause however I would like to understand  why my idea with having clause does not work. :)

Here's my SQL query:

```
        select g.name, count(il.invoice_line_id) tracks_sold from genre g 
          inner join track t 
          on t.genre_id = g.genre_id
          inner join invoice_line il
          on il.track_id = t.track_id
          inner join invoice i
          on i.invoice_id = il.invoice_id
          inner join customer c
          on c.customer_id = i.customer_id
          group by 1 
          having c.country = 'USA'
          order by tracks_sold desc
```

It returns following result:

[image]

It is wrong. It should return instead below table:

[image]

When I write the query by first separating tracks sold in USA and then joining and grouping by genre it works fine. I wonder why having clause does not work here as I expected.

Below you can find outlook of the database with columns that I use:
[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In most dialects that won't even run. `HAVING` is applied after the `GROUP BY` (which itself is applied after `WHERE`). By that time there is no `c.country` in scope, it's already been aggregated away. Do you mean `WHERE c.country = 'USA' GROUP BY g.name`?

Comment: Yes, I was confused by the rule that `where` can't be used with aggregation functions however that only means filtering by aggregative function, not any other column. I've changed to what you've suggested and it works, many thanks! :)